# Cannot store summernote value into database, it returns [object Object]

Tags: php, jquery, summernote

Im trying to store a **summernote** value into **database** with **ajax/jquery** but it just send this value to database field -----> **[object Object]**.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Desciption</label>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="summernote"></textarea>
</div>                                   
<div class="text-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="publish">Publier</a>
</div>
```

**Js file:**

```
$("#publish").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();     
    var description = $('textarea[name="description"]').html($('.summernote').code());  

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/newpost.php',
        data : 'description=' + description,    

        success : function(data){                               
            alert(data);
            location.reload();                  
        }
    });         
});
```

**newpost.php**

```
    require_once('../config/connect.php');      

    $description = $_GET['description'];



    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO `forum_posts` (`description`) VALUES(?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($description));

    if($stmt){
        echo "done ......................";
    }else{
        echo "error ..................";
    }
```

Comment: `console.log(description)` in your JS code, and you'll probably find it's a jquery object.

Comment: By the way i think a POST request is more appropriate for this.

Comment: I tried the POST request but Its not working either. Can you please provide me with an example? maybe your method would help

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `$('textarea[name="description"]').html($('.summernote').code()` with `$('textarea[name="description"]').val()`

Comment: It's not working either.
it always return [Object Object]

I found this :
https://gist.github.com/soomtong/6635053

it says we should use code() instread of val(); but both are not working

Comment: $('textarea[name="description"]').val() send empty data into database

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the class of summernote editor to your textarea then pick the post value using the textarea name.

For example:

```
<textarea name="description" class="full-editor"> </textarea>
```

then:

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do $("#description").code();  with summernote.  The fonction will search the value himself, not need to indicate the full path juste, the textarea/div root.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this same issue using MVC 5.2.3/Razor with an ajax form. As of the summernote 0.8.1, it is recommended to use [$("#mysummernote").summernote('code')](http://summernote.org/examples/#click-to-edit), but this doesn't work. It gives you a `<div>` and sometimes extra `<span>` all enclosed in `[ ]` with your summernote text. This causes it be recognized as an object.

Unless there's some trick to using this, it makes summernote a pain when updating to a database as you would need to parse text. That being said, I found a work around. If someone has a better, working solution please let me know.

```
$("#mysummernote").destroy();    // This updates it for some reason.
$("#mysummernote").summernote('code').children().prop('outerHTML');
```

So if your text in the summernote is

- my text

the jQuery above should return

```
<ul><li>my text</li></ul>
```